# VR Adding Locomotion: Walk

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Using Unity2017.3.1f1 Personal (64 bit) to build a VR app for Android, using Cardboard VR SDK. The purpose of the app is to allow users visualize data in an immersive way.

Currently want to do something similar to the scene view where one can move forward by going where one's looking but with the Cardboard single button i'm just gonna give the ability to move forward.

Built a Canvas where user can select what type of locomotion he/she wants: teleport or walk.

[The teleport works fine as you can see here](http://gph.is/2oVetzH).

When the user selects walk, the following error shows in the Console:

> NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object
>
> Player.TryWalk () (atAssets/Player.cs:44)
>
> Player.Update () (at Assets/Player.cs:37)

My Player script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public enum InputMode
{
    NONE,
    TELEPORT,
    WALK
}

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    public static Player instance; //Singleton design pattern: only one instance of the class appears
    public InputMode activeMode = InputMode.NONE;

    [SerializeField]
    private float playerSpeed = 3.0f;

    void Awake()
    {
        if(instance != null)
        {
            GameObject.Destroy(instance.gameObject);
        }
        instance = this;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        TryWalk();
    }

    public void TryWalk()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) && activeMode == InputMode.WALK)
        {
            Vector3 forward = Camera.main.transform.forward;

            Vector3 newPosition = transform.position + forward * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed;

            transform.position = newPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

The Player script was added as component of Player:

[image: hierarchy]

[image: player]

When the button Walk is pressed, the Active Mode changes to WALK, as you can see in the next image.
[image: walk]

Still, even though this happens, the user is not able to Walk.

**What can I do to solve this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Camera.main;` was returning null.

In order to fix it, had to have the camera in my scene tagged `MainCamera` as you can see in the next image.

[image: camera]

[See it working here.](https://giphy.com/gifs/unity-vr-unity3d-dejBiGXLM3WU2nYsqH)